# Riverpod mixin for ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> and an Action<SomeIntent>

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a mixin that I am using on multiple riverpod `ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget>` classes and it works great. But now I want to use the same mixin with an `Action<SomeIntent>` so that I can re-use code instead of duplicating it. The problem seems to be in the way that I'm currently definining the mixin:

```dart
mixin QuickFilesMixin<T extends ConsumerStatefulWidget> on ConsumerState<T> {...}
```

Restricting the mixin to `on ConsumerState<T>` is the reason I can't also mix it in with the `Action` which makes sense. But if I try to unrestrict the mixin using something like...

```dart
mixin QuickFilesMixin {...}
```

...then I am able bolt it onto both the ConsumerStatefulWidget and the Action but it breaks because I lose access to `ref` inside the mixin which is crucial.

Is there a way that I can access `ref` inside a mixin that can be mixed in with multiple `ConsumerStatefulWidget`s and also an `Action<SomeIntent>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution is to add the properties/methods you need in your mixin, defining them as abstract.

For example if you want your mixin to be applicable on any object with a `WidgetRef ref` property, you can do:

```dart
mixin MyMixin {
  WidgetRef get ref;
}
```

This enables:

```dart
class MyState extends ConsumerState<...> with MyMixin {}
```

And also allows:

```dart
class MyIntent extends Action<SomeIntent> with MyMixin {
  MyIntent(this.ref);
  final WidgetRef ref;
}
```